# Do nerves grow out from within or in from the skin?

Tags: central-nervous-system, peripheral-nervous-system, autonomic-nervous-system, cranial-nerves

### The Question:

> Do nerves grow out from within or in from the skin?

### Thoughts:

My guess is outwards.

However, I have a vague memory of a study involving frogs that I read about in a pop science book - I forgot which - that took skin from the back & chest of a bunch of frogs, swapped them, then tested their reactions. ***If*** I remember correctly, some of the frogs wiped their chest when the skin on their back was stimulated (and/or *vice versa*). That would suggest that they grow inward from the skin.

Some vaguely formed hypotheses:

1. Nerves grow inwards from skin.
2. Nerves grow outwards from, say, the brain.
3. Some combination of 1. and 2.

### Background:

I have no formal training in biology. I read a handful of textbooks on evolution for fun though, like *"99% Ape"*, *"Why Evolution is True"*, and some of Dawkins' work, including *"The Selfish Gene"*.